# How to loop through multiple dynamic input fields in php to insert them in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `item` in my `mySql` database with the columns named `item` and `price`. With jquery, I used a button that generates fields for the input of multiple items and their price. But what should be the `php` codes for looping through the inputs for inserting them respectively? (Like ***item 1*** with ***price 1***)
Some thing like this
[image: that I'm trying to achieve]

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;

    $('p#add_field').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        count += 1;
        $('#container').append(
            'Item: <input type="text" id="item_' + count + '" name="item[]' + '"/>\n\
             Unit price: <input type="text" id="price_' + count + '" name="price[]' + '"/><br>'
        );
    });

});
</script>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
    if ($_POST['item']) {

        foreach ($_POST['item'] as $key => $value) {
            $sql_item    = sprintf("INSERT INTO item (item) VALUES ('%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($value));
            $result_item = $db->query($sql_item);
        }        
    }
    echo "<h1>User Added, <strong>" . count($_POST['fields']) . "</strong> item(s) added for this user!</h1>";
    $db->kill();
}
?>
<?php if (!isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) { ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div id="container">
            <label>Available items</label>
            <p id="add_field"><button type="button" href="#">Add new item</button></p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit">Save items</button>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Could you not just make an items table with an auto increment ID column, item name and item price column? Also you could remove the else statement after the `if ($_POST['item'])`.

Answer (score 1):

Your storage of data is abnormal, change the `item` table so it has an auto increment `ID` column and an `item name` and `item price` column.

Change your code in the `foreach` loop to reflect the table change.

Your approach to sanitizing your SQL query is not the best way, you are using mySQLi to connect to the database so use the class' built in function to [prepare and execute queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Can you kindly give an example how I should write the  foreach loop with the changed table structure that you've suggested? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I was trying something like this - 
`foreach(array_combine($_POST[‘item_name’] , $_POST[‘item_price’]) as $iname=> $iprice) {

   $a = mysql_real_escape_string($iname);
   $b = mysql_real_escape_string($iprice);

   $sql =  mysql_query ("INSERT INTO item (item_name, item_price) VALUES ('".$a."','".$b.”’)”);
}`
It somehow does the job but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: You don't need to do that, did you check the link in my answer?

Comment: @RajibBiswas check the link I have given and provide an attempted solution we can help you from there.